# Is it possible to have subdomain in separate server

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, subdomain

Supose I have a domain `www.foo.bar` registered to point DigitalOcean.

Is it possible to have a subdomain like `staging.foo.bar` pointing Amazon AWS? Any tips regarding of how to achieve this?

Comment: SF is for professional sysadmins managing IT systems in business environments. Are you a professional sysadmin? :)

Comment: No, where is this written?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the A record for `staging.foo.bar` to your AWS IP address.

Comment: We do this just like @adam says; one for the main address to a hosted site for the public, and a subdomain to another server for company use.